# Undefined property: stdClass PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, stdclass

I ran into a little problem that I am unable to solve.

So I get this error message:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$wins

But I did an var_dump of my object and it has wins in it...

I dont understand what's up.

Here is how I initiate my object:

$champStats->gp += 1;

```
    if($matchStats->winner)
        $stats->wins += 1;
    else
        $stats->loss += 1;
```

And this is how I call it:

```
   $stats=Cache::get($key);

   <p>GP: {{$stats->gp}}</p>
   <p>Wins: {{$stats->wins)}}</p>
```

And when I do var_dump($stats), I get this:

```
object(stdClass)[584]
 public 'gp' => int 2
 public 'wins' => int 1
```

....

I just don't understand what the problem is...

Here is my full code for initating the object (Note that I use laravel framework):

```
  $playerStats = new \stdClass();
  $matches = Match::all();
  $matchStats = $match->stats;

  $playerStats->gp += 1;

  if($matchStats->winner)
        $playerStats->wins += 1;
  else
        $playerStats->loss += 1;

  $playerStats->kills += $matchStats->kills;
  $playerStats->deaths += $matchStats->deaths;
  $playerStats->assists += $matchStats->assists;

 Cache::forever($key,$playerStats);
```

And in my views, I call it like this:

```
   $stats=Cache::get($key);

   <p>GP: {{$stats->gp}}</p>
   <p>Wins: {{$stats->wins)}}</p> (This is where I get my error)
   <p>Kills: {{$stats->kills)}}</p>
   <p>Deaths: {{$stats->deaths)}}</p
```

Here is the full error code:

> ErrorException in 653ee84185b758200c82957f836de32f line 56:
>   Undefined property: stdClass::$wins

Thanks for your help,
Ara

Comment: 1. Make sure you show us your **full** and **real** code 2. Also please show us your **full** and **exact** error message which you get (And also mark it with a comment in the question)

Comment: I added the full code

Comment: Also please mark the line where you get the error in the question + full error message

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you get the notice during the increment. Try checking if the variable is set before you increment.

```
if($matchStats->winner) {
    if(!isset($stats->wins)) {
        $stats->wins = 1;
    }
    else {
        $stats->wins++;
    }
}
else {
    if(!isset($stats->loss)) {
        $stats->loss = 1;
    }
    else {
        $stats->loss++;
    }
}
```

Another (probably better) option is to initialize `$stats->wins` and `$stats->loss` to 0 when you create `$stats`.

Comment: 1. It's only a guess (but a good one) 2. Why not just initialize the properties before it with 0 so you don't have to check it?

Comment: @Rizier123 hah I was editing my post with just that suggestion :)

Comment: I edited my inital post to give more details. But the initialisation works just fine. It's when I am calling the object from my view that it's giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to access to values with array convention

```
$stats=Cache::get($key);
<p>GP: {{$stats['gp']}}</p>
<p>Wins: {{$stats['wins'])}}</p>
```

Good luck !

Comment: Where do you see `array` in this: `object(stdClass)[584]` ?